# In the endgame, black had only two blocked pawns. It is his turn. Is it stalemate or must he move his king?

Tags: rules, endgame, stalemate

In the endgame, Black had only two blocked pawns. It is his turn. Is it stalemate or must he move his king?

My opponent claimed that the king cannot move if all other remaining pieces are blocked.

Comment: **Did the Black King have a legal move available?**  The question would benefit from the inclusion of the position in question.

Answer (score 2):

> My opponent claimed that the king cannot move if all other remaining pieces are blocked

Whether the king can move has nothing to do with other pieces being blocked. It has to do with all the squares it can go to being attacked by one or more enemy pieces. If the king has no **LEGAL** moves and all the other pieces are blocked and the king is not in check then *that* is stalemate.

Read the full rules [here](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018).